# Google BigQuery list tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to list all tables in my BigQuery, but I don't know how to do it, I try search but I didn't find anything about it.

I need to know if the table exists, if it exists I search for record, if not I create table and insert record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending where/how you want to do this, you can use CLI, API calls or client libraries. Here you have all the info about [listing tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#listing_tables_in_a_dataset)

As an example, if you want to list them using [Command Line Interface](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#bq_10), you can do it like:

`bq ls <project>:<dataset>`

If you want to use normal SQL queries, you can use the `INFROMATION_SCHEMA` [**Beta feature**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#tables_view)

```
SELECT table_name from `<project>.<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
```

(project is optional)

Comment: I never used the command line, just the query editor. Can I do this in the query editor?

Comment: I modified my answer, hope it helps